# Keyboard random failure in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have not been able to track down why random actions in Visual studio 2010 will cause the keyboard and/or mouse to start performing different actions than anticipated or more often than not, stop responding to certain actions.

I never loose complete control, but I could return to VS from another screen and any of the following could occur:

- Clicking on text with the mouse, acts like I have the shift key down and tries to highlight entire areas
- arrow keys will no longer move the cursor
- Delete, backspace or enter will stop responding

I am not sure that it is always after returning from running an application/debug, but that is definitely a majority of the times that I encounter the issue.  Most of the time I have to completely shutdown VS and restart to get keyboard functionality back.  Most of the time, other functions still work such as typing.

I should note, that I always check another application that those keys are responding as they are expected to verify it is only in VS that the problem is occurring.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I have occasionally, and for along time, seen "sticky" modifier keys (Ctrl, Alt, Shift) in VS, especially after quitting a debug session. For me it's usually the Ctrl key which turns Shift-F5 (stop debugging) into Ctrl-Shift-F5 (restart debugging). That's a bit frustrating.

The best fix I know is: when you notice this behavior, give each of the modifier keys a press to "un-stick" them, which sounds like what you're doing when you "check another application."